# Creating a hot standby with Postgres 9.6

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a hot standby with Postgres 9.6 on Ubuntu 16.04.

I can successfully ssh from my standby machine to the primary as `postgres`.

I have removed `/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main` and running:

`pg_basebackup -h <primary IP> -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main -U rep -v -P --xlog-method=stream`

that successfully creates a new `main` directory.

In `/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf`, I have:

- added this servers IP address to the `listen_addresses`
- set `wal_level = replica`
- set `hot_standby = on`

I've created a `recovery.conf` with:

`standby = on`

`primary_conninfo = 'host=<primary ip> port=5432 user=rep password=<password>`

On `sudo service postgres start`, postgres starts and I see:

`2016-12-22 07:24:29 UTC [10728-1] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2016-12-22 07:13:44 UTC
2016-12-22 07:24:30 UTC [10728-2] LOG:  redo starts at 3/4D000028
2016-12-22 07:24:30 UTC [10728-3] LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 3/4D000130
2016-12-22 07:24:30 UTC [10728-4] LOG:  redo done at 3/4D000130
2016-12-22 07:24:30 UTC [10728-5] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2016-12-22 07:24:30 UTC [10732-1] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2016-12-22 07:24:30 UTC [10727-4] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2016-12-22 07:24:30 UTC [10734-1] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet`

Should I not see a message where it tries to contact the master?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> 2016-12-22 07:24:30 UTC [10728-3] LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 3/4D000130
> 2016-12-22 07:24:30 UTC [10728-4] LOG:  redo done at 3/4D000130
> 2016-12-22 07:24:30 UTC [10728-5] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound ?protections are now enabled
> 2016-12-22 07:24:30 UTC [10732-1] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
> 2016-12-22 07:24:30 UTC [10727-4] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
> ```

Looks like your `recovery.conf` file has ignored.  Are you shure that the `recovery.conf` has the right permissions (basically owned by the user that run the service, usually `postgres`)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The `recovery.conf` has the same permissions as the other conf files.

Answer (score 1):

`recovery.conf` needs to be in the same directory as the database e.g.

`/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main` **NOT** the `/etc/postgresql` config directory

I now see

`LOG:  entering standby mode
LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 6/680021E8
LOG:  invalid record length at 6/680021E8: wanted 24, got 0
LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 6/68000000 on timeline 1`